# "I left" vs "i am leaving it for tommorow"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

What is grammatically correct: 
I left it (a job task) for tomorrow 
or
I am leaving it (a job task)  for tomorrow ?

Isn't it strange that we use past tense to describe an action that will happen in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> I left it (a job task) for tomorrow

does not describe a future action. It describes an action in the past - the action of deciding to work on the task tomorrow. The work may be done in the future, but decision to not work on the task before that time happened *in the past*.

Comment: To further build on this, both can be correct depending on when the action, in this case deciding to work on the task tomorrow, is done. You would use "I am leaving" if you are making that decision now, and "I left" if you made that decision earlier.